# Angularjs 2 with visual studio 2013 (update 5)

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to develop an application using angularjs 2 in VS 2013 (update 5) IDE.

I am using the live examples here - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/a1-a2-quick-reference.html

I don't have nodejs/npm installed in my machine (as company dont support it as of now)...so I am referring to the npm modules using CDN urls as mentioned in the systemjs.config.js.

When I build (build/rebuild option in visual studio) my application, I get errors like - 
Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.

If I run my application - I get error as I mentioned in this post (when I press F12).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044718/angularjs-2-in-visual-studio-2013-not-translpiling

I tried to copy @angular modules from another machine - and it seems Cannot find module '@angular/core' - this issue is going away.

Do we need to have npm modules installed in locaal machine for angular 2 to work?, If so how the plunker examples are working?

If we refer the CDN urls instead of npm modules locally, will the "moduleresolution" entry in tsconfig.js work?

EDIT : Solution[image]

Comment: checkout the example on Angular2 doc site. You don't need to install node.js

Comment: No where  they mentioned that we dont need to install npm modules locally...I too think we dont need to install...but in that case do we need to specify some other value for moduleresolution?

Comment: download the [live example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html) to your local. It should run without issue.

Comment: Could you tell me what IDE r u using?

Comment: it is nothing to do with IDE, but you can use VS Code.

Comment: It is not working in VS 2013 - I have seen people reporting so many issues with vs 2013/2015...while running angular2.

Comment: It is NOTHING to do with IDE. I used both VS code and VS2015. It it just javascript.

Comment: BTW, why do you need to build it ? it is javascript. Just use your browser to browse the landing page.

Comment: I dont want to build it. I was trying to run it from VS 2013..and it gave me an error as I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044718/angularjs-2-in-visual-studio-2013-not-translpiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It seems VS 2013 is not supporting tsconfig.json as of now.**

You can define the same configuration you are using in the project file. for instance:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
can be defined in the project file as:

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>commonjs</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptModuleResolution>node</TypeScriptModuleResolution>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>True</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>True</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8784

Also make changes to your systemjs.config.js as follows. (I dont know if this is right thing to do but it seems working).

```
var config = {
    // DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      tsconfig: false
    },
    meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    },
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
```

[image: @MaxiSam - I]

Comment: honestly, I still think it is weird. When you set `<TypeScriptEnabled>false</TypeScriptEnabled>` and `<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>false</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled> `  VS shouldn't generate any js from ts, which mean it doesn't need to read tsconfig at all.

Comment: that's true...but in the systemjs.config.js, we should tell angular that it should not look for that file, right ?. And CompileOnSave is true in my case.

Comment: not really, systemjs.config.js is the configuration for systemJS. So set it as true means telling systemJS to read tsconfig when systemJS transpile typescript. Set it as false, it will just use the default value. IMO, you should set CompileOnSave false and delete all existing transpile from your project.

Answer (score 0):

I see. Try this in you proj file.(you need to unload it to edit it)

```
<!-- <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersio‌​n)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualSt‌​udioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" /> --> 
<PropertyGroup> 
   <TypeScriptEnabled>false</TypeScriptEnabled> 
</PropertyGroup> 
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this, but not helping me :(

Comment: really ? this should hide your typescript tab in project properties page

Comment: <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptEnabled>false</TypeScriptEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <TypeScriptEnabled>false</TypeScriptEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: Above is my cs proj file now...And I removed entries:<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    </TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>true</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>false</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>commonjs</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>

Comment: TypeScript tab is not disabled for me after that change. I am using vs 2013 with HTML TypeScript template

Comment: how about this line ?  `<!-- <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersio‌​n)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualSt‌​udioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" /> -->`  you need to remove target from proj

Comment: I tried to comment that line, now I don't have any build errors. But the run time error is still there (which is the same error). Also, it is not creating .d.ts (but creates *.js files) from.ts files now (which it was creating before under app folder)

Comment: you don't need VS to create anything for you. That is what this line doing. `<TypeScriptEnabled>false</TypeScriptEnabled>` and i don't know what you mean by run time error. from browser console ?

Comment: did you use the example from official site ?

Comment: yes - In fact I created a new web app with the "live example" you mentioned above. Do you have it running in you machine?

Comment: please see the new "EDIT"

Comment: And how about post your browser screenshot with console opened in the bottom

Comment: hei..I think got it Workinggggggggggggggggg - I think VS 2013 is not supporting tsconfig.json as of now...I followed https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8784 link... Also editted systemjs.config.js as  var config = {
    // DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      tsconfig: false
    },
    meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "t