# Angular2 Quickstart in Git TypeScript Files has errors in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: angular

The typescript was not recognized. I don't know if I need to configure something or what?
[image: Snap]

Comment: Try using VS Code instead. Its a free editor and works well with TypeScript. If you are really stuck using VS 2013, check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234012/angularjs-2-with-visual-studio-2013-update-5

Comment: @DeborahK the code's completely fine and it works during runtime. It's just that I don't want to see my .ts file with corrugated lines. Thanks anyway.